# divide payments for periods

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions

I have a total value that contain user payments since he registered.
For each year since his registration date, user must pay a premium membership BUT it doesn't have to be payed in the same year. User can pay e. eg. for three year back. Or for next three following years in advance.

Rates for years are as follows:

```
year | rate
2014 | 100
2015 | 100
2016 | 50
2017 | 150
2018 | 100
```

That's the values the user should pay. But he can transfer a less or more money that is required. Let say a user has payed a 438$. It doesn't matter when he did this. It could be the 2014 or the current year. We only want to know if he has payed all that he should, that are fees from 2014 to current year.

What I want to do is to divide the total amount of his transfers (calculated and stored in a variable) for each year that should be payed to check that he has everything paid or has excess payment/underpayment.

Result I would like to get:

```
year | rate | payed
2014 | 100  | 100
2015 | 100  | 100
2016 | 50   | 50
2017 | 150  | 150
2018 | 100  | 38
```

So the user has payed all that he should up to date and has 38$ excess payment.

Using loop/cursor I can do that, but can't think of window function to use. Any hint? Can't find how to query google for this case.

Sample (solution is working but looking for window function equivalent)

```
DECLARE @total DECIMAL = 438

;WITH data AS 
(
    SELECT *, @total - (SELECT SUM(tt.rate) FROM 
        (VALUES
        (2013, 100),
        (2014, 100),
        (2015, 100),
        (2016, 100),
        (2017, 100),
        (2018, 100)) tt([Year], Rate)
        WHERE tt.[Year] < t.[Year]) AS Payed
    FROM (VALUES
    (2013, 100),
    (2014, 100),
    (2015, 100),
    (2016, 100),
    (2017, 100),
    (2018, 100)) t([Year], Rate)
),
prepared AS
(
    SELECT d.[Year], @total AS Total, d.Rate, 
        CASE 
            WHEN ISNULL(d.Payed, d.Rate) <= 0 THEN NULL 
            WHEN @total < d.Rate THEN @total ELSE ISNULL(d.Payed, d.Rate) 
        END AS Payed
    FROM data d
)
SELECT p.[Year], @total AS Total, p.Rate, 
    CASE 
        WHEN p.Payed >= p.Rate THEN p.Rate 
        ELSE p.Payed 
    END Payed 
FROM prepared p
```

Comment: Where is payed `coming` from?  "divide the total amount of his transfers per years to check that he has everything paid"  Say what? Why are we dividing ? wouldn't you want to sum the transfers per year to see what's been paid?  I'm lost.  Consider showing tables involved, sample data and expected results to help clarify your question.

Comment: Added sample code and additional clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server 2012+ it is very easy to calculate the total outstanding (or overpaid) amount using `SUM() OVER (ORDER BY...)`.

**Sample data**

```
DECLARE @TotalPaid money = 438;

DECLARE @Rates TABLE (Y int, Rate money);
INSERT INTO @Rates (Y, Rate) VALUES
(2014, 100),
(2015, 100),
(2016,  50),
(2017, 150),
(2018, 100),
(2019, 100);
```

**Query**

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        Y
        ,Rate
        ,SUM(Rate) OVER (ORDER BY Y 
        ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS SumRate
    FROM @Rates
)
,CTE2
AS
(
    SELECT
        Y
        ,Rate
        ,SumRate
        ,@TotalPaid - SumRate AS PaidExtra
    FROM CTE
)
SELECT
    Y
    ,Rate
    ,SumRate
    ,PaidExtra
    ,CASE WHEN PaidExtra >= 0
        THEN Rate
        ELSE Rate + PaidExtra
    END AS Paid
FROM CTE2
ORDER BY Y
;
```

**Result**

```
+------+--------+---------+-----------+--------+
|  Y   |  Rate  | SumRate | PaidExtra |  Paid  |
+------+--------+---------+-----------+--------+
| 2014 | 100.00 | 100.00  | 338.00    | 100.00 |
| 2015 | 100.00 | 200.00  | 238.00    | 100.00 |
| 2016 | 50.00  | 250.00  | 188.00    | 50.00  |
| 2017 | 150.00 | 400.00  | 38.00     | 150.00 |
| 2018 | 100.00 | 500.00  | -62.00    | 38.00  |
| 2019 | 100.00 | 600.00  | -162.00   | -62.00 |
+------+--------+---------+-----------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I follow 100 % but maybe this:

Working example: http://rextester.com/OCHHR61883

```
DECLARE @total DECIMAL = 438

;WITH data AS 
(
    SELECT *, @total - (SELECT SUM(tt.rate) FROM 
        (VALUES
        (2013, 100),
        (2014, 100),
        (2015, 100),
        (2016, 100),
        (2017, 100),
        (2018, 100)) tt([Year], Rate)
        WHERE tt.[Year] < t.[Year]) AS Payed
    FROM (VALUES
    (2013, 100),
    (2014, 100),
    (2015, 100),
    (2016, 100),
    (2017, 100),
    (2018, 100)) t([Year], Rate)
),
prepared AS
(
    SELECT d.[Year], @total AS Total, d.Rate
          , case when @total-sum(rate) over( Order by year asc)<0  then 0 
                 else @total-sum(rate) over( Order by year asc) end  as RunningTotal

    FROM data d
)
Select * from prepared
```

Which gives us:

```
+----+------+-------+------+--------------+
|    | Year | Total | Rate | RunningTotal |
+----+------+-------+------+--------------+
|  1 | 2013 |   438 |  100 |          338 |
|  2 | 2014 |   438 |  100 |          238 |
|  3 | 2015 |   438 |  100 |          138 |
|  4 | 2016 |   438 |  100 |           38 |
|  5 | 2017 |   438 |  100 |            0 |
|  6 | 2018 |   438 |  100 |            0 |
+----+------+-------+------+--------------+
```

Or now that I look closer perhaps this:

http://rextester.com/AFR44863

```
DECLARE @total DECIMAL = 438

;WITH data AS 
(
    SELECT *, @total - (SELECT SUM(tt.rate) FROM 
        (VALUES
        (2013, 100),
        (2014, 100),
        (2015, 100),
        (2016, 100),
        (2017, 100),
        (2018, 100)) tt([Year], Rate)
        WHERE tt.[Year] < t.[Year]) AS Payed
    FROM (VALUES
    (2013, 100),
    (2014, 100),
    (2015, 100),
    (2016, 100),
    (2017, 100),
    (2018, 100)) t([Year], Rate)
),
prepared AS
(
    SELECT d.[Year], @total AS Total, d.Rate
          , case when @total-sum(rate) over( Order by year asc) > 0  then d.rate
                 when @total-sum(rate) over( Order by year asc) < 0 and sum(rate) over( Order by year asc) > 0 and d.rate+@total-sum(rate) over( Order by year asc) < 0 then 0              
                 when @total-sum(rate) over( Order by year asc) < 0 and sum(rate) over( Order by year asc) > 0 then d.rate+@total-sum(rate) over( Order by year asc)
                 end  as Paid

    FROM data d
)
Select * from prepared


+----+------+-------+------+------+
|    | Year | Total | Rate | Paid |
+----+------+-------+------+------+
|  1 | 2013 |   438 |  100 |  100 |
|  2 | 2014 |   438 |  100 |  100 |
|  3 | 2015 |   438 |  100 |  100 |
|  4 | 2016 |   438 |  100 |  100 |
|  5 | 2017 |   438 |  100 |   38 |
|  6 | 2018 |   438 |  100 |    0 |
+----+------+-------+------+------+
```

Or a different approach based on the 1st query:
http://rextester.com/BVSDS50299

```
DECLARE @total DECIMAL = 438

;WITH data AS 
(
    SELECT *, @total - (SELECT SUM(tt.rate) FROM 
        (VALUES
        (2013, 100),
        (2014, 100),
        (2015, 100),
        (2016, 100),
        (2017, 100),
        (2018, 100)) tt([Year], Rate)
        WHERE tt.[Year] < t.[Year]) AS Payed
    FROM (VALUES
    (2013, 100),
    (2014, 100),
    (2015, 100),
    (2016, 100),
    (2017, 100),
    (2018, 100)) t([Year], Rate)
),
prepared AS
(
    SELECT d.[Year], @total AS Total, d.Rate
          , case when @total-sum(rate) over( Order by year asc) < 0  then 0 
                 else case when @total-sum(rate) over( Order by year asc)> d.rate then d.rate else @total-sum(rate) over( Order by year asc) end  end
    as RunningTotal

    FROM data d
)
Select * from prepared
```

which gives us the same result as the 2nd query.